# predefine test.coverprofile flag

Tags: bash, go

I am analyzing code coverage using go tooling. 
First I create test binary

```
go test -coverpkg="github.com/ypapax/flags" -c
```

Then I run it

```
./flags.test -test.coverprofile=/tmp/out.out
cat /tmp/out.out
```

And see profile content

```
PASS
coverage: 100.0% of statements in github.com/ypapax/flags
mode: set
github.com/ypapax/flags/main.go:5.12,7.2 1 1
```

The question is:
Is it possible to predefine flag `-test.coverprofile=/tmp/out.out` so I could run without `test.coverprofile` flag

`./flags.test
cat /tmp/out.out`

and still see `/tmp/out.out` content.
My test code:

```
package main

import "testing"

func TestRunMain(t *testing.T) {
    main()
}
```

My main code:

```
package main

import "time"

func main(){
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
}
```

The full code is here:

```
go get github.com/ypapax/flags && cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/ypapax/flags
```

My question may seem weird but it may be helpful if a lot of functional tests already written which call `flags.test` binary and it would be nice to avoid adding `-test.coverprofile` to each `flags.test` binary call.

I see 2 possible solutions:

1. Set `-test.coverprofile` inside go code. How to do it?
2. Use bash to wrap up binary with a predefined flag. But in this case, there should not be extra files. It must be the only one `flags.test` with predefined `-test.coverprofile` flag. How to do it?

I appreciate any advice. Thanks

## Update

I am trying to run @dmitris answer

```
package main

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "os/exec"
    "log"
    "fmt"

    . "github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata"
)

func main() {
    prog, err := Asset("flags.test")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    dest := "/tmp/flags.test" // could also use https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#TempFile
    coverProfile := "/tmp/flagstest.out"
    err = ioutil.WriteFile(dest, prog, 0755)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    cmd := exec.Command(dest, "-test.coverprofile", coverProfile)
    output, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Output: %s, Error: %s", string(output), err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(output))
    fmt.Println("Coverprofile saved to ", coverProfile)
}
```

Not clear from where to import `Asset` func on line `prog, err := Asset("flags.test")`. 
Running `go build -o wrapper wrapper.go` gives me

```
./wrapper.go:13: cannot convert "flags.test" (type string) to type bindata.Asset
./wrapper.go:13: assignment count mismatch: 2 = 1
```

Comment: its not clear to me what problem you're trying to solve. if you just dont want to type it, `alias flagcv="./flags.test -test.coverprofile=/tmp/out.out"`

Comment: the problem is I need to change the code in 500 places (already written bash tests which call my binary without `-coverprofile` flag) and paste `flagcv` instead of `./flags.test`. I would like to keep that tests without changes just replace `flags.test` binary and it should have flag `coverprofile` on board. Maybe `flags.test` name is misleading. In fact, I rename `flags.test` to `flags` and run as vanilla binary then check cover profiles.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to do it, you can do the following - the idea is to pack the "original" test binary into the one that you will distribute and which will unpack the "original" and call it with the required arguments:

- install `go-bindata`: `go get -u github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata/...`
- create a test executable `flags.test`: `go test -c -cover`
- create a wrapper .go file (for example, wrapper.go): `go-bindata -o wrapper.go flags.test`
- edit the wrapper.go file to add a `main` function to extract the binary and call it with the desired arguments:

wrapper.go

```
func main() {
    prog, err := Asset("flags.test")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    dest := "/tmp/flags.test" // could also use https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#TempFile
    coverProfile := "/tmp/flagstest.out"
    err = ioutil.WriteFile(dest, prog, 0755)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    cmd := exec.Command(dest, "-test.coverprofile", coverProfile)
    output, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Output: %s, Error: %s", string(output), err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(output))
    fmt.Println("Coverprofile saved to ", coverProfile)
}
```

- compile the wrapper program for distribution: `go build -o wrapper wrapper.go`

Output:

```
$ go run wrapper.go
PASS
coverage: 100.0% of statements

Coverprofile saved to  /tmp/flagstest.out
```

Comment: another really hacky way would be to modify the testing package in the stdlib - change this line https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/testing/testing.go#L234 to put the filepath of where you want the coverprofile to go instead of the default empty string.  You should have this file locally in /usr/local/go/src/testing/testing.go; to rebuild go, run `./make.bash` in /usr/local/go/src.  As I said, it's a hack - but should work if needed :)

Comment: thanks, not clear from where to import `Asset` function, please see my update above